# What happens when creating a variable?

Tags: c#, variables

```
void Method1()
{
string str = 
client.GetString("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

}
```

What exactly happens when the first line in Method1 is carried out?

I understand memory is set aside for the string variable `str`, but does the right-hand side of the statement also get carried out at this stage? i.e. does it actually retrieve a value for the right-hand side?

Comment: What do you mean by "RHS"?

Comment: @Alejandro: Right hand side of the assignment.

Comment: If the RHS didn't get carried out, what would be the point of having it?

Comment: Yes. This is declaration (`string str`) and initialisation (`str = ...`) in one statement.

Comment: Code isn’t run line by line, especially when lines are cut in the middle of an actual code unit. Therefore it’s hard to say what you want to know exactly here and what to answer. There is only one line, which calls a method and stores the result in a variable. Compiler may throw the whole variable assignment out since it’s not used anywhere so there might not be any memory allocations.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right it was a pretty obvious question, I was trying to figure out whether it was worthwhile storing a variable and then doing work on that variable later on.

Comment: "whether it was worthwhile storing a variable and then doing work on that variable later on" - quite possibly; depends *entirely* on context, though

Answer (score 13):

This depends a lot on what you do next. There's a *very* good chance that the compiler will actually remove `str` *completely* if you don't use it (*unless* you use it in the next step, or the things you do between now and then are "net zero" in terms of stack positions). It will still execute the call to `client.GetString(...)`, of course; the question is *what does it do with the result?* There's various ways the compiler can interpret this:

- as a local:

stack space for the local is reserved as part of the stackframe entry; after the call to `GetString` the compiler emits `stloc` (or a variant)

- as an ambient stack value

no explicit stack space is reserved for the local; after the `GetString()` it is simply left where it is for the next operation to consume (for example, this would be perfect if followed by a static call like `Console.WriteLine(str);`); it might also be cloned (`dup`) if needed multiple times

- popped

no explicit stack space is reserved for the local; after the `GetString()` it is simply dropped (`pop`)

- as a field

this would apply for iterator blocks and async methods; very complicated to explain

Ultimately, if you really want to know, you need to look *at the real code*, then look at the IL - ideally compiled in "release" mode.

You can see examples of some of these in [this test code on sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

or copied here:

```
void Method1_Popped()
{
    string str = client.GetString("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
}
void Method2_LeftOnStack()
{
    string str = client.GetString("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
void Method3_Local()
{
    string str = client.GetString("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
    for(int i = 0;i < 3 ; i++) DoSomethingElse();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

becomes:

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance void Method1_Popped () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 18 (0x12)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld class SomeClient Foo::client
    IL_0006: ldstr "http://msdn.microsoft.com"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance string SomeClient::GetString(string)
    IL_0010: pop
    IL_0011: ret
} // end of method Foo::Method1_Popped

.method private hidebysig 
    instance void Method2_LeftOnStack () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2063
    // Code size 22 (0x16)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld class SomeClient Foo::client
    IL_0006: ldstr "http://msdn.microsoft.com"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance string SomeClient::GetString(string)
    IL_0010: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0015: ret
} // end of method Foo::Method2_LeftOnStack

.method private hidebysig 
    instance void Method3_Local () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
    // Code size 42 (0x2a)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] string,
        [1] int32
    )

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldfld class SomeClient Foo::client
    IL_0006: ldstr "http://msdn.microsoft.com"
    IL_000b: callvirt instance string SomeClient::GetString(string)
    IL_0010: stloc.0
    IL_0011: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0012: stloc.1
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0013: br.s IL_001f
    // loop start (head: IL_001f)
        IL_0015: ldarg.0
        IL_0016: call instance void Foo::DoSomethingElse()
        IL_001b: ldloc.1
        IL_001c: ldc.i4.1
        IL_001d: add
        IL_001e: stloc.1

        IL_001f: ldloc.1
        IL_0020: ldc.i4.3
        IL_0021: blt.s IL_0015
    // end loop

    IL_0023: ldloc.0
    IL_0024: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0029: ret
} // end of method Foo::Method3_Local
```

or as ASM:

```
Foo.Method1_Popped()
    L0000: mov ecx, [ecx+0x4]
    L0003: mov edx, [0xe42586c]
    L0009: cmp [ecx], ecx
    L000b: call dword [0x2ef71758]
    L0011: ret

Foo.Method2_LeftOnStack()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov ecx, [ecx+0x4]
    L0006: mov edx, [0xe42586c]
    L000c: cmp [ecx], ecx
    L000e: call dword [0x2ef71758]
    L0014: mov ecx, eax
    L0016: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L001b: pop ebp
    L001c: ret

Foo.Method3_Local()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov ecx, [ecx+0x4]
    L0006: mov edx, [0xe42586c]
    L000c: cmp [ecx], ecx
    L000e: call dword [0x2ef71758]
    L0014: mov ecx, eax
    L0016: call System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)
    L001b: pop ebp
    L001c: ret
```

Comment: sorry i have no idea what you said, but i will save the reply and hopefully one day i can come back to it and be able to understand it :) thanks marc, i've also saved the new edits

Comment: @jimbob I've added more context that may help you... or not :) and note: this is just in terms of IL; the JIT compiler can then *do even more voodoo*; there is also a "JIT Asm" tab on sharplab.io

Comment: @jimbob ultimately, there's no way of answering this that doesn't involve talking about stackframes and IL...

Comment: It seems you made a copy&paste mistake in the assembly listing: `Foo.Method3_Local` is identical to `Foo.Method2_LeftOnStack`.

Answer (score 1):

Memory allocation depends on how exactly the variable is used and where it's declared. In this case, being a local variable within a method*, memory is reserved as soon as the method is called (and not when execution reaches the place of its declaration), regardless of what could happen afterwards. So memory is set aside even if the `client.GetString("http://msdn.microsoft.com")` isn't called at all (couldn't happen at all here, but in more complex code that's possible).

Note that you mention

> when the first line in Method1 is carried out

This method has a single line, which consist in declaring a variable and assigning a value to it from calling another method. The fact that you've written it as two physical lines is irrelevant, as logically, your whole code consist of a single step. Again, variable "declaration" and allocation happens as soon as the method is called, and the rest of the line happens when execution reaches that point.

The execution of the line actually has two stages: the first, the `GetString` method gets called. Second, its return value gets assigned to the local variable.

As Marc Gravell pointed out, things can become more complex. The compiler may decide to simply not create the variable at all, or arrange things differently, as long as that produces the same result (something known as [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)). The rest of this answer assumes that the compiler didn't optimized anything and created a binary that matches *exactly* the given code, but in release builds we can expect some differences.

*(and not captured by a lambda)

Comment: note - it is very possible (likely, even), that no stack space is actually reserved here; many local variables are elided *completely* by the compiler

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure, in the case the compiler optimizes out the variable (probably in this case it does). For the simplicity sake, I'm assuming that the compiler compiles the code **exactly** as stands in the question, no optimizations involved. In real life, the actual binary might differ significantly from the code, as long as it produces the same result.

Comment: One possible source of confusion: How can the compiler reserve memory at the start of the method when it doesn't even know how long the string is going to be? It might make sense to point out that space for the string *content* gets allocated somewhere within the `GetString()` call, and `Method1` just stores a *reference* (to avoid the ugly word "pointer") to that space, with the amount of storage needed for the reference being always the same, independent of string length.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case, the assignment happens immediately. Later on you'll learn about funny things like lazy loading, async and delegates and then you'll see instances where variables aren't initialised immediately. But don't worry, by the time you learn about those things, you'll know enough that it won't be difficult to understand.

And congrats on learning the most beautiful programming language in the world.